# Как правильно сформулировать аннотацию?

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно сформулировать: "Монография предназначена для студентов высших учебных заведений по специальностям .... " или "Монография предназначена для  студентов высших учебных заведений, обучающихся по специальностям ....". В первом варианте складывается впечатление, что специальности относится к учебным заведениям, а не к студентам. Хотя встречала во многих источниках в аннотациях именно этот вариант.

Answer (score 4):

Второй вариант убедительнее, хотя предлог "по" я бы опустил (обучающихся чему - специальности; обучающихся по программе, работающих по специальности). В первом же варианте трудно отделаться и от странной конструкции "студент по специальности", которая конкурирует с упомянутой вами "заведение по специальности". Как вариант: "Монография адресована студентам ВУЗов, специализирующимся в области..." (если, конечно, речь о профильной специальности, а не просто об одном из предметов).

Answer (score 3):

**Беспроигрышный вариант:** Монография предназначена для студентов высших учебных заведений, обучающихся по специальностям ...

Но интересно, что выражения вида "программа для студентов специальности/ по специальности" **действительно встречаются**, хотя кажутся некорректными.

**Из словаря:**

СПЕЦИАЛЬНОСТЬ,  2. Отдельная отрасль науки, техники, мастерства или искусства; профессия, основная квалификация. С. инженера, врача, слесаря, повара. Получить, освоить, приобрести с. По специальности кто-л. - строитель. У него - редкая с. Работать по специальности.

Здесь специальность - это профессия, поэтому выражение "он студент по специальности" кажется неправильным, однако в вузах специальность - **это особый термин**, обозначающий профильное направление при обучении.

Поэтому, возможно, в этом значении вариант "Монография предназначена для студентов высших учебных заведений по специальностям..." вполне приемлем.

Answer (score 2):

Правильный вариант:  ***"Монография предназначена для студентов высших учебных заведений, обучающихся по специальностям..."*** А в первом варианте действительно получается корявая фраза "для студентов высших учебных заведений по специальностям..." В единственном числе безграмотность этой фразы более очевидна. К примеру: *я студент высшего учебного заведения по специальности геология*. Или ещё нелепее: *я студент по специальности геология*.

Answer (score 1):

Монография предназначена для обучающихся в высших учебных заведениях по специальностям...

Монография призвана помочь обучающимся в высших учебных заведениях по специальностям...

Студентов, возможно, и следовало бы выделить из всей массы обучающихся, но в вузе обитают ещё абитуриенты и аспиранты.

Answer (score 1):

> В первом варианте складывается впечатление, что специальности
>   относится к учебным заведениям

Только у читателя совсем стороннего, не вникшего в смысл. Думаю, что у человека, уже открывшего учебник и читающего аннотацию, таких проблем не возникнет. 
Варианты равнозначны, но первый короче. Искать какой-то панацейный вариант в данном случае смысла не вижу. На каждый чих не здравствуешься. А отходить от шаблона без особой нужды - только портить.